# std::vector push_back and class constructor not being called?

Tags: c++, vector

I have class like this

```
class variable
{
    public:
        variable(int _type=0) : type(_type), value(NULL), on_pop(NULL)
        {
        }

        virtual ~variable()
        {
            if (type)
            {
                std::cout << "Variable Deleted" <<std::endl;
                on_pop(*this);
                value=NULL;
            }
        }

        int     type;
        void*   value;
        typedef void(*func1)(variable&);
        func1 on_pop;
}
```

And then I push instances into a std::vector like this:

```
stack.push_back(variable(0));
```

I expect that the destructor of variable will be called but the if won't enter until a value is assigned to type because I expect the constructor I provide will be called when the instance is copied into the vector. But for some reason it is not.

After calling stack.push_back the destructor (of the copy?) is ran and type has some random value like if the constructor was never called.

I can't seem to figure what I am doing wrong. Please help! ^_^

EDIT:

Ok here is a self contained example to show what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class variable
{
    public:
        variable(int _type=0) : type(_type), value(NULL), on_pop(NULL)
        {
        }

        ~variable()
        {
            if (type)
            {
                std::cout << "Variable Deleted" <<std::endl;
                on_pop(*this);
                value=NULL;
            }
        }

        int     type;
        void*   value;

        typedef void(*func1)(variable&);
        func1 on_pop;
};

static void pop_int(variable& var)
{
    delete (int*)var.value;
}

static void push_int(variable& var)
{
    var.type = 1;
    var.value = new int;
    var.on_pop = &pop_int;
}

typedef void(*func1)(variable&);
func1 push = &push_int;

int main()
{
    std::vector<variable>   stack;

    stack.push_back(variable(0));
    push(stack[stack.size()-1]);

    stack.push_back(variable(0));
    push(stack[stack.size()-1]);

    stack.push_back(variable(0));
    push(stack[stack.size()-1]);

    return 0;
}
```

The program above outputs the following:

```
Variable Deleted
Variable Deleted
Variable Deleted
Variable Deleted
Variable Deleted
Variable Deleted

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.602 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: It’s not clear what actually happens, and what you expect to happen: even though the compiler is allowed to optimise here, it *will* properly initialise all objects so this code works exactly as I would expect it to. Clearly, your expectations are different but I don’t understand what they are, or why.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I added a SSCCE to show what I am trying to do. If the destructor gets called 6 times, I expect the constructor be called the same amount of times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to RVO and NRVO. This basically means that the compiler can skip creating an object if it's redundant- even if it's constructor and destructor have side effects. You cannot depend on an object which is immediately copied or moved to actually exist.

Edit: The actual value in the `vector` cannot be ellided at all. Only the intermediate variable `variable(0)` can be ellided. The object in the `vector` must still be constructed and destructed as usual. These rules only apply to temporaries.

Edit: Why are you writing your own resource management class? You could simply use `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter. And your own RTTI?

Every object that was destructed *must* have been constructed. There is no rule in the Standard that violates this. RVO and NRVO only become problematic when you start, e.g., modifying globals in your constructors/destructors. Else, they have no impact on the correctness of the program. That's why they're Standard. You must be doing something else wrong.

Ultimately, I'm just not sure exactly WTF is happening to you and why it's not working or what "working" should be. Post an SSCCE.

Edit: In light of your SSCCE, then *absolutely nothing* is going wrong whatsoever. This is entirely expected behaviour. You have not respected the Rule of Three- that is, you destroy the resource in your destructor but make no efforts to ensure that you actually *own* the resource in question. Your compiler-generated copy constructor is blowing up your logic. You must read about the Rule of Three, copy and swap and similar idioms for resource handling in C++, and preferably, use a smart pointer which is already provided as Standard like `unique_ptr` which does not have these problems.

After all, you create six instances of `variable`- three temporaries on the stack, and three inside the vector. All of these have their destructors called. The problem is that you never considered the copy operation or what copying would do or what would happen to these temporaries (hint: they get destructed).

Consider the equal example of

```
int main()
{
    variable v(0);
    push_int(v);
    variable v2 = v;
    return 0;
}
```

Variable `v` is constructed and allocates a new `int` and everything is dandy. But wait- then we copy it into `v2`. The compiler-generated constructor copies all the bits over. Then both `v2` and `v` are destroyed- but they both point to the same resource because they both hold the same pointer. Double delete abounds.

You must define copy (shared ownership - `std::shared_ptr`) or move (unique ownership - `std::unique_ptr`) semantics.

Edit: Just a quick note. I observe that you actually don't `push` into items until after they're already in the vector. However, the same effect is observed when the vector must resize when you add additional elements and the fundamental cause is the same.

The destructor is called 6 times. *A* constructor is called six times. Just not the one you intended.

Comment: I’m sure this is the right answer but I don’t see how: the *constructor* cannot be elided, only the  *copy*. Hence, `type` should be initialised properly to 0 and the destructor of the temporary, if it exists at all, should *not* execute the `if` block.

Comment: How should I go to accomplish this simple wish of having an object properly initialized when I insert it into a std::vector? ^_^

Comment: @damian: It will be. Just not copied. The *target* object must still be constructed and destructed, it will just not be copied. Hence it is good practice to have one class that manages one resource acquire it in constructor and destroy it in destructor.

Comment: So if I need to conditionally run some code in the object destructor I cannot do it when I insert it into a std::vector? Is there any way I could accomplish this without having to write my own container?

Comment: @damian: No, that's not how it works. Classes like `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` have to do resource management logic all the time and don't have a problem with this.

Comment: @DeadMG There I posted a SSCCE showing that I push_back 3 times and the IF block get's entered 6 times.

Comment: @damian: Ah! I thought it was *less* times, not *more*.

Comment: So:

1. I statically instance an object. constructor is called. 
2. I push it into a vector. A copy is created and copy constructed with the original one and stored into the vector. 
3. The original object is destroyed. 
4. I access the element in the vector and change it's values. 
5. I statically instance anoter object. Constructor is called. 
6. I push it into the vector. A copy is created and copy constructed with the values of the first element in the vector. 
... and so on. (possibly more copies involved).

I can see it now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've been reading some more about the intrinsics of different containers and, apparently, the one that does the job I'm trying to accomplish here is **std::deque**.